# Extract value of NSDate()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, calendar, dateformatter

I am trying to get a number of the day in 14 days from today. 
I want to work with the number so it has to be an integer value.

But I don't find a solution for extracting the information I need. So my question is how to get the date in 14 days so I can work with it?

```
let daysToAdd = 14
let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: daysToAdd, to: Date())

//This is where I want to get
print ("In 14 days it is \(day).\(month).\(year)
```

Comment: what are you getting the value of newDate with this code?

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani 2019-04-13 08:56:55.911178+0200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 14, to: Date())

let calendar = Calendar.current
print(calendar.component(.year, from: newDate!)) // Year
print(calendar.component(.month, from: newDate!)) // Month
print(calendar.component(.day, from: newDate!)) // Day
```

Comment: Why don’t you add 2 weeks?

Comment: @LeoDabus The question is asked for add Int number of days and extracts it that's why.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Calendar.component` to get to those values:

```
let cal = Calendar.current
if let newDate = cal.date(byAdding: .day, value: 14, to: Date()) {
    let day = cal.component(.day, from: newDate)
    let month = cal.component(.month, from: newDate)
    let year = cal.component(.year, from: newDate)
    print ("In 14 days it is \(day).\(month).\(year)
}
```